# Complicated repeated function

Tags: javascript

Please Help me to solve this complicated loop. I’m calling 5 API URL but each of them should be called on a specific number of times then it should start to second, third, fourth and fifth URL and start again from top to bottom again and gain.

```
https://www.example1.com should be called 4 times
https://www.example2.com should be called 10 times
https://www.example3.com should be called 8 times
https://www.example4.com should be called 9 times
https://www.example5.com should be called 6 times
```

Should end on https://www.example5.com and again start from top https://www.example1.com 
Unstoppable loop.

I highly Thanks & appreciate that anyone which answers this.

My code:

[This is what I have tried so fo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSTOu.jpg)

The result of the code is commented inside the above code.

Comment: Please don't take a screenshot of code. Copy and paste the code here.

Comment: I have tried a lot to paste my code for better reference but could not suceed with stack overflow roles I only uploaded an image. If anyone can tell me how to share my code please let me know

Comment: @sam show your code as text

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: This is my code :https://www.codepile.net/pile/7Plo91MN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable as counter for each function like below,

```
var numberOfExecution=0;
function1(); // Start the procedure
function1()
{
 // do api call
 .......
 // after finishing your task, check if this function execution hits desired number
 numberOfExecution++;
 if(numberOfExecution==4)
{
 numberOfExecution=0;
 function2();
}
else
{
function1();
}
}
function2()
{
 // do api call
 .......
 // after finishing your task, check if this function execution hits desired number
 numberOfExecution++;
 if(numberOfExecution==6)
{
 numberOfExecution=0;
 function3();
}
else
{
function2();
}
}
```

In these process, one after another execution will continue achieving desired number of execution.

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick reply I use var counter = 1; inside the function it works but my code does not start again and again

Comment: Now see the full procedure, you need to reset the counter after achieving a desired number of execution and shifing to another api call.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!